# Prepend multiple values to a list

Tags: list-manipulation

If I have a list such as list={1,2,3,4,5}, how can a prepend multiple values to the list?. For example what I want is to prepend 6 zeros prior to {1,2,3,4,5} to get `{0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,3,4,5}`. I tried using `Prepend[list, Table[0, 6]]` but this give me `{{0,0,0,0,0,0},1,2,3,4,5}` which would be all the six zeros as the first element rather than each zero being an element.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have lots of options, such as:

```
list = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
zeros = ConstantArray[0, 3];

Catenate[{zeros, list}]

(* or *)

Join[zeros, list]

(* or *)

Flatten[{zeros, list}, 1]
```

> `{0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}`

As of Mathematica 12.1, you also have this option:

```
{Splice[zeros], Splice[list]}
```

> `{0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}`

Which I guess is equivalent to doing this, which also works in earlier versions:

```
{Sequence @@ zeros, Sequence @@ list}
```

> `{0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}`

But `Splice` has the additional advantage that it is not evaluated before it occurs in the context of a list, which means that we can use it with `Prepend`, and salvage your initial attempt:

```
Prepend[list, Splice[zeros]]
```

> `{0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}`

(`Prepend[list, Sequence @@ zeros]` would not have have worked since `Sequence` would have been applied immediately, which nicely highlights the utility of the `Splice`.)

Comment: Thank you very much !

Comment: You can of course do `Prepend[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, Unevaluated[Sequence @@ {0, 0, 0}]]`, but `Splice[]` is surely easier to handle.

Comment: @J.M. good point, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you want to [`Join`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Join.html) two lists.

Comment: Thank you @Szabolcs! That's exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use [`ArrayPad`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArrayPad.html) and [`PadLeft`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PadLeft.html):

```
ArrayPad[list, {6, 0}]
```

> ```
> {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
> ```

```
PadLeft[list, 6 + Length@list]
```

> ```
>  {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
> ```